If for $E(X)$: $E[X] = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq m)$ then for $E(X^2)$?
$E[X^2] = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m \cdot P(X \geq m)$ ?
need to prove: $\text{Var}(X) = 2 \cdot\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m P(X \geq m) \ - E(X)(E(X) + 1)$
I did the easy part (I hope that's right) : $E(X^2) + E(X) = 2 \cdot\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m P(X \geq m)$
If my version is correct (about $E[X^2]$), then everything is wrong:
$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m \cdot P(X \geq m) + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq m) = 2 \cdot\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m P(X \geq m)$
help please
X takes non negative integer values

Your question is very unclear. What is the question you are trying to answer? (You have a question mark in the title and then another on the first line.) What is $D(E)$?

Can $X = 0$? What you've shown seems to imply that $X\geq 1$.

Are you asking how to express $E[X^2]$ in terms of a sum over $P(X\geq m)$?

From your formula for $E[X^2]+E[X]$ and your formula for $E[X]$, you should immediately realize that the formula you propose for $E[X^2]$ is wrong.

Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb N$ be a random variable. Using some summation properties we were able to obtain:
$$E[X]:=\sum_{x=0}^\infty x\cdot \mathbb P[X=x]=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^x\mathbb P[X=x]=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{x=m}^\infty \mathbb P[X=x]=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \mathbb P[X\geq m]$$
You can't just guess an analogous formula for $E[X^2]$, you must derive it from the definition. Note that $x=\sum_{m=1}^x1$, and similarly $x^2=\sum_{m=1}^x(2m-1)$. Now:
$$E[X^2]:=\sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2\cdot \mathbb P[X=x]=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^x(2m-1)\mathbb P[X=x]=\ldots $$
